# Mapview with toolbar like by default map iphone

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I want to make mapview with toolbar like iphone maps.
I googled it but i cant get any appropriate things that can give me any idea to develop it.
So anyone has idea about map like below.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your mapView setup and now you're trying to add the navBar? All you need to do is use a standard navigation bar from the interface builder and place it at the bottom of the viewController. Hook up the appropriate outlets and IBActions and then you're good to go.

Comment: do you have any links to the example how to do so?